# Why do <a> tags disappear in sitefinity list items?

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-5

In sitefinity, I created a list. In that list, I created 6 items, each with an  tag. This is the a tag that was generated:

```
<a href="/home" sfref="[f669d9a7-009d-4d83-ddaa-000000000002]0ca3c443-9c91-6473-a96c-ff00000b9007">Home</a>
```

I then go to my page, and drag and drop a list into a widget slot. Then I choose my test list in the settings, and I get no links.

I open the website, and when looking in the browser inspector, there is definitely no link. All that comes up for the above example is "Home" in the li tag.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.

When you drag and drop the list widget into your page, in the list settings there are options for different lists. I was using a simple list, but I should have been using a page list.

Answer (score 1):

It will work when you will remove sfref attribute then it will working fine

**Your Code**

```
<a href="/home" sfref="[f669d9a7-009d-4d83-ddaa-000000000002]0ca3c443-9c91-6473-a96c-ff00000b9007">Home</a>
```

**Replace With**

```
<a href="/home">Home</a>
```